# MySQL Select all where DATETIME field is not NULL

Tags: mysql

I am having trouble selecting the proper values from this query:

```
SELECT * FROM discounts 
WHERE DiscLimit > 0 AND DiscLimit >= DiscRedeemed 
OR DiscExp IS NOT NULL AND DiscExp <= NOW()
```

`DiscExp` is a `DATETIME` field that defaults to `NULL`.

I am trying to select current unexpired discounts from the database:

`SELECT * FROM discounts WHERE`:

1. The limit is > 0 (a limit exists) AND the limit is >= the number
   redeemed
2. An expiration exists (not null) and the expiration is in
   the future

It seems to be retrieving values where the `DATETIME` field is `NULL`. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Try putting parentheses around the conditions: `(a AND b) OR (c AND d)`

Comment: yeah `or` always should be scrutinzed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need parentheses! Try this:

```
SELECT * FROM discounts 
WHERE (DiscLimit > 0 AND DiscLimit >= DiscRedeemed) 
OR (DiscExp IS NOT NULL AND DiscExp <= NOW())
```

But, from your question, I'm not sure if the `OR` is correct. If you want it to meet all of the following conditions:

- The limit is > 0 (a limit exists)
- The limit is >= the number redeemed
- An expiration exists (not null)
- The expiration is in the future

You want, this:

```
SELECT * FROM discounts 
WHERE DiscLimit > 0 AND DiscLimit >= DiscRedeemed
AND DiscExp IS NOT NULL AND DiscExp <= NOW()
```

Or, if you want it to meet all of the following conditions:

- The limit is > 0 (a limit exists)
- The limit is >= the number redeemed
- The expiration is in the future or does not exist (IS NULL)

You want this:

```
SELECT * FROM discounts 
WHERE DiscLimit > 0 AND DiscLimit >= DiscRedeemed
AND (DiscExp IS NULL OR DiscExp <= NOW())
```

Note that you don't actually need to use `DiscExp IS NOT NULL AND DiscExp <= NOW()`, because `NULL` does not evaluate to being `<= anything`.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your logic is the parentheses.  However, you can just write:

```
SELECT d.*
FROM discounts d
WHERE DiscLimit > 0 AND
      DiscLimit >= DiscRedeemed AND
      DiscExp <= NOW();
```

The `NULL` comparison is unnecessary, because any of the comparison operators return not-true when one or both operands are `NULL`.